# BigQueryML standard scaler of struct data

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to apply standard scaling on this column "A" of this data:

```
[
  {
    "index": "0",
    "A": {
      "list": [
        {
          "element": "0.0"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "index": "1",
    "A": {
      "list": [
        {
          "element": "3.0"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "index": "2",
    "A": {
      "list": [
        {
          "element": "0.0"
        },
        {
          "element": "0.0"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "index": "3",
    "A": {
      "list": [
        {
          "element": "0.0"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I tried with this query:

```
SELECT 
    index,
    (select ML.STANDARD_SCALER(x.element) over() from unnest(A.list) as x) as scaled_A,
FROM `table`
```

but got the error: ***ML analytic functions are not allowed in correlated subqueries***

Any hint on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT index, 
  STRUCT(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(scaled_A AS element)) AS list) A
FROM (
  SELECT index,
    ML.STANDARD_SCALER(x.element) OVER() scaled_A
  FROM `table` t, UNNEST(A.list) AS x 
)
GROUP BY index
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

```
[
  {
    "index": "0",
    "A": {
      "list": [
        {
          "element": "-0.4082482904638631"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "index": "1",
    "A": {
      "list": [
        {
          "element": "2.0412414523193148"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "index": "2",
    "A": {
      "list": [
        {
          "element": "-0.4082482904638631"
        },
        {
          "element": "-0.4082482904638631"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "index": "3",
    "A": {
      "list": [
        {
          "element": "-0.4082482904638631"
        },
        {
          "element": "-0.4082482904638631"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```